# Add indicator to button background

Tags: java, android, xml, button, drawable

I am trying to add an indicator to my button.
similar to this: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wyyet.png)

How can I do so? I am able to make a solid background but I don't know how to add the small blue block part. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this radiobutton in your xml file

```
<RadioButton
android:id="@+id/home"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/home_selector"
android:button="@android:color/transparent"
android:checked="true" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/favourite"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/fav_selector"
    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
    android:checked="true" />
....
```

and now you can create a selector for every different radio button as you wish

home_selector.xml

```
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/home_selected"
    android:state_checked="true" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/home_normal" />
```

fav_selector.xml

```
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/fav_selected"
    android:state_checked="true" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/fav_normal" />
```

Like this you can create selectors for which ever radio button you may want

Answer (score -2):

You can do it like this
By adding a view with your color above the button

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Set its visibility on its click

Comment: its not best practice to setVisibility to view unless and until you don't have other option.